# Redux-Observable - Dispatch multiple actions that have to be run in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, redux-observable

Using **redux-observable**, I'm trying to spawn off multiple `WORK` actions from a single epic, like so:

```
( action$, state$ ) => {
   return action$.pipe(
      ofType( 'SPAWN' ),
      flatMap( action => {
         return [
            { type: 'WORK', payload: 'a' },
            { type: 'WORK', payload: 'b' },
            { type: 'WORK', payload: 'c' },
         ];
      } )
   )
}
```

The actions are firing off fine, but problem is, these `WORK` actions are async and thus they are handled by another epic, like so:

```
( action$, state$ ) => {
   return action$.pipe(
      ofType( 'WORK' ),
      flatMap( action => {
         const promise = new Promise( resolve => {
            setTimeout( () => {
               resolve( { type: 'SET', payload: action.payload } );
            }, Math.random() * 5000 ); // promise may resolve at different times
         } );

         return promise;
      } )
   )
}
```

At the reducer for action `SET`, I would expect, the sequence to be in order, regardless of the randomness of the `setTimeout` above, since the flatMap is returning promises. The result should be like so:

```
a
b
c
```

Nonetheless, I'm getting random orderings for the `SET` action, for example:

```
b
c
a
```

Would really appreciate it if anyone can point me to the right direction and aid me in my understanding.

**Working Update**
As per the answer from @Oles Savluk, I've edited the `WORK` epic to be as follows:

```
( action$, state$ ) => {
   return action$.pipe(
      ofType( 'WORK' ),
      concatMap( action => {
         const promise = new Promise( resolve => {
            setTimeout( () => {
               resolve( { type: 'SET', payload: action.payload } );
            }, Math.random() * 5000 ); // promise may resolve at different times
         } );

         return promise;
      } )
   )
}
```

Notice that the use of `concatMap` makes actions of the type `WORK` to be arranged in the stream sequentially. One action waits for another to complete before executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`concatMap` operator](http://rxmarbles.com/#concatMap) which will emit items **sequentially** instead of `flatMap`(mergeMap) which do this concurrently

If you are new to Rx you can read [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) to understand the difference between flattening operators.

Comment: Should this `concatMap` be used in the `SPAWN` epic or the `WORK` epic? It seems to me that once you dispatch common Redux actions, it is out of scope from Rx's control. Thus, the `WORK` epic does not follow the correct order resolving from the Promise.

Comment: Thanks @Oles Savluk, I finally understand what you mean by using `concatMap`. It should be used in the `WORK` epic.
Basically what we're trying to say when we use `concatMap` is _I know we have a few of these actions down in the line, but don't execute all of them flatly, instead, execute them one by one_.

Answer (score 1):

With `flatMap`, all emissions of the inner observable are forwarded to the outer observable in order of their occurance. Now, with a `Promise`, that emission is created only when the Promise resolves, not immediately. Therefore, you receive the "random" order that is created by the timeout.

Comment: Thank you @ggradnig for pointing this out. Is there any solution for my case in this respect?